# HTML5 Video: Stop at specific frames with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a standard HTML5 video element. I would like to pause the video at specific frames (not minutes) via pure JavaScript.

```
<video id="media-video" controls>
    <source id="media-source" src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also given is a JavaScript array, which defines frames, where the video should stop.

```
var stopframes = [300, 600, 900];
```

Unfortunately, I have only a solution for stopping the video at a specific time by seconds:

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    if (mediaPlayer.currentTime > stopframes[0]) {
        ...
    }
});
```

How can I stop the video at one specific frame with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VideoFrame.js](https://github.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame) for this.

`stopVideoFor` takes some amount of milliseconds that I use to stop the video whenever the current frame is in `stopframes` (`if (stopframes.includes(frame)) {`):

```js
var stopframes = [30, 60, 90, 132];

var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
var video = VideoFrame({
  id: 'video',
  frameRate: 29.97,
  callback: function(frame) {
    if (stopframes.includes(frame)) {
      stopVideoFor(1000);
    }
  }
});

function stopVideoFor(ms) {
  video.video.pause();
  video.stopListen();

  setTimeout(() => {
    video.video.play();
    video.listen('frame');
  }, ms);
}

$('#play-pause').click(function() {
  if (video.video.paused) {
    video.video.play();
    video.listen('frame');
    $("#play-pause").html('Pause');
  } else {
    video.video.pause();
    video.stopListen();
    $("#play-pause").html('Play');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video height="180" width="100%" id="video"> 
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
</video>

<div id="controls">
  <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing us to this. Unfortunately, it is not always frame-precise as I reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613008/javascript-frame-precise-video-stop. In case you have some ideas, I'm happy to hear them