Error using webcodecs to decode h264 data and display on browser from http fetch
I am getting :

(index):60 Error during fetch or decode process: DataError: Failed to execute 'decode' on 'VideoDecoder': A key frame is required after configure() or flush(). If you're using AVC formatted H.264 you must fill out the description field in the VideoDecoderConfig.
at fetchAndDecodeJson ((index):55:24)"

when trying to decode the below h264 data in a json format via webcodec:
[
    {
        "type": "key",
        "pts": 0,
        "data": "Z0LgK28gAflBAQAAAwAAAPoAAIIAAO1BAQAAAwAAAPoAAOIwFA=="
    },
    {
        "type": "delta",
        "pts": 1,
        "data": "aMuHsyAABfsAAABAqAAABfsBAwABxAAAAgAAABfsBAwABxAAAgA=="
    },
    {
        "type": "delta",
        "pts": 2,
        "data": "aMuHsyAABfsAAABAqAAABfsBAwABxAAAAgAAABfsBAwABxAAAgA=="
    },
    {
        "type": "delta",
        "pts": 3,
        "data": "aMuHsyAABfsAAABAqAAABfsBAwABxAAAAgAAABfsBAwABxAAAgA=="
    }
]


My index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>decode H.264 to Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="output" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <script>
    async function fetchAndDecodeJson() {
      try {

        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/datatest.json");
        const jsonData = await response.json();

        console.log("Fetched JSON Data:", jsonData);

        const canvas = document.getElementById("output");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const videoDecoder = new VideoDecoder({
          output: (frame) => {
            canvas.width = frame.displayWidth;
            canvas.height = frame.displayHeight;
            ctx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0);
            frame.close();
          },
          error: (e) => console.error("decode error:", e),
        });

        const codecSupport = await VideoDecoder.isConfigSupported({
          codec: "avc1.42E01E",
        });

        if (!codecSupport.supported) {
          throw new Error("codec not supported");
        }

        videoDecoder.configure({ codec: "avc1.42E01E" });

        //decode each chunk from the JSON data
        for (const item of jsonData) {
          const { type, pts, data } = item;

          //base64 video data
          const rawData = Uint8Array.from(atob(data), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0));

          //decode the video chunk
          const chunk = new EncodedVideoChunk({
            timestamp: pts * 1000, 
            type: type, 
            data: rawData,
          });

          videoDecoder.decode(chunk);
        }

        console.log("decode success");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("decode or fetch error:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchAndDecodeJson().catch(console.error);
  </script>
</body>
</html>


the test frames are fetched but not decoded
enter image description here
i tried fiddling with sps and pps in the  decoder config without success

The error implies you need to set decoderConfig.description, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73184093/decode-mp4-video-with-videodecoder

@James yes i noticed that part, but it's unclear how to fill up the description and i didnt find an exact way for avc in documentation

@stackexplorer0202 Your "data": parts are holding some H264 metadata called SPS and PPS (is Z0LgK... and aMuHs... respectively). They are useful for setting up the decoder,  so now you need another next "data" but one that makes a keyframe... Attach all 3 things as long one array then send to decode with Webcodecs.

@VC.One which 3 things exactly SPS, PPS and what else

@stackexplorer0202 re-fixed ... You need SPS, PPS, and Keyframe (is first video frame) ... See if this Answer helps you to setup things. PS: Your shown base64 SPS says the codec config is 42E02B but in your JS code videoDecoder.configure is using 42E01E (they are close, but might not decode)... Do you know which one is correct? Also tell the encoding side to first convert bytes to hex string, then do the base64 encode after (ie: decode gives hex string like FF A8 45 D9) ... I'll try to write an Answer when time allows.

I think i just managed to decode the packet in the example in the answer you linked without errors, it displays a yellow square and it worked without me setting the description, i suppose the problem is in my input packets in the JSON, any idea where i can find other example packets to display in chain, or how can i extract them from a video and format them as in your example packet and put them in a JSON as before?

What's the backstory with this format?  Sending your video in base64 in JSON, and in one giant JSON array like that, is a memory and CPU nightmare.
